# retrofit give me timeout

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit

I am using retrofit to connect to a rest api on a server, but I am receiving timeout exception even I set the connection, read and write timeout as you can see in my code. 
The request is arriving to the server and working, there is a change on the DB, but without receiving any response. Can anyone help please? what I am doing wrong?

```
public static Retrofit getClientMoreTimeOut() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                                    .connectTimeout(200000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                                    .readTimeout(200000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                                    .writeTimeout(200000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                                    .build();

        Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                       .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                                       .client(okHttpClient)
                                       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Comment: How long does the server side processing usually take?

Comment: if you say "The request is arriving to the server and working" meaning the server is handling the request, but is it responding?

Comment: 30-40 second at server side